How to mock the lambda layer in nodejs
I'm using lambda layer in my lambda function. Since lambda layer code will not be present in the local system, I'm not able mock the layer functions
My code looks like this
// index.mjs
import layer from '/opt/layer'

layer.update();

Trying to mock the layer in index.test.mjs
jest.mock('/opt/layer', ()=>{
  update:()=>{
// mocking the response
}
});

I'm getting: Cannot find module '/opt/layer' from index.mjs
Is there any way to mock the lambda layers
I tried adding "modulePathIgnorePatterns" for jest config, but did not work

If the modules is not preset you should pass virtual in the options
like this:
jest.mock('/opt/layer', () => ({
  update: () => {
    // mocking the response
  }
}), {
  virtual: true
});


Shame this had no upvotes.. This was the top hit when I googled my issue and this quickly solved it!
